# American Indian and others escape Earth that is controlled by a computer

Tags: story-identification, spaceship, artificial-intelligence, planets, mind-control

Please help me identify a science fiction book series I read in the early 80s. The story starts with an American Indian that is given an injection so he remembers he's not just a member of a tribe, but a person on planet Earth that is controlled by a computer program that has taken over control of all humanity for its own supposed good.  He escapes Earth along with a few others and they steal a ship parked out by Jupiter pursued by a type of cop which is actually the subconscious of this program. The ship travels to different planets where each person gets transformed into the inhabitants of that planet. Of course they succeed in bringing down this giant program thus freeing humanity to grow.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/67159/book-about-a-group-of-escaped-prisoners-with-tattooed-faces (which has an accepted answer)

Answer (score 6):

I think that the series *Rings of the Master* by Jack L. Chalker, is what you're searching for. It is comprised of the following books :

- *Lords of the Middle Dark*
- *Pirates of the Thunder*
- *Warriors of the Storm*
- *Masks of the Martyrs*

## Points of similiarty

- Computer (master) has taken over the world. It then sent humanity to the star, but changed the people so that they where adapted to the world they were sent to (i.e. no terraformation, more humanformation). The change is hereditary. People changed once can not be changed back (i.e. you can only change form once in your life).
- On most worlds, the tech level is low. Only a few people (the brightest) are aware of the situation, and are tasked with managing the world under the computer. Those people have access to better technology.
- A set of rings can bring the computer down. Each ring *must* be in possession of a human with power. But the human does not have to know what his ring can do. Also, how to use the ring is not a known information
- The hero is an Indian that discovers the existence of the rings and their use
- One of the team member is in fact a robotic policeman that has rebelled against the computer. Another cop is trying to stop them (in the first books at least)

Please see the following URL for other points...
[I'm looking for a sci fi book with a tribal woman, hermaphrodites, and implanting minds into new bodies](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/52163/im-looking-for-a-sci-fi-book-with-a-tribal-woman-hermaphrodites-and-implantin/56568#56568)